# How to separately run each test in karma-runner

Tags: unit-testing, testing, webpack, tdd, karma-runner

I often get tests crush when they are running together. I mean when i use `describe.only()` for run single test block i have no errors. But when i run all tests together this test block shows errors. I suppose that it's happened because of merging all tests in single file tests.webpack.js. 
Is there any approach to run each test separately to avoid any influence?

Comment: This is a pretty common issue when you have `async` tests and you forget to close some of them correctly. Make sure all your `async` tests are either calling the `done` callback or returning promises.

Comment: i'll check it and will post some feedback